# Advanced requests and classes with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Recently I have been reading around and doing research on the best options for threading my program. The program will import a library I have created which consists of multiple classes that all contain their own respective requests session and headers, different set of requests etc. Upon doing my research all I have found are examples in which people are using one session, or not doing multiple POST and GET requests, or are using deprecated versions of modules. How could I go about using asyncio to run hundreds of these objects doing POST and GET requests at the same time?

I'm not asking for the code to be written for me, just a simple place to start or some concepts I should familiarize myself with. Threading/asynchronous programming is incredibly overwhelming. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

requests-futures (https://pypi.org/project/requests-futures/) is very easy to implement asynchronous programming in python 3.x.

As an example:

```
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession

def async_calls(list_of_urls):
    """Returns future objects for each url."""
    futures = []
    session = FuturesSession()
    for url in list_of_urls:
        scan_id, history_id, host_id, creation_date = host
        task = session.get(url)
        futures.append((task, ip_query_params))
    return futures
```

== In calling function:

```
futures = async_calls(urls)
results = [f.result() for f in futures]
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still just looks like a generic scan of a list of URLs, I need the capability to run multiple requests sessions.